# "Not enough free disk space" error after deleting huge log file from flash drive

Tags: package-management, hp, disk-usage, log, pcie

All started this morning when I couldn't boot into Gnome, and got a blinking cursor.

I realised nvidia-driver-460 had unmet dependencies, but I couldn't fix it since running `sudo apt install --fix-broken nvidia-driver-460` prompted the error `You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Then I realised that I was constantly getting a PCIe-related error, which seems to be a common issue for HP machines that produces huge log files. Hence, I booted on a flash drive and deleted a log file that was around 150 GB.

However, despite having done that, I still get `Not enough free disk space` when trying to fix broken dependencies on recovery mode. And running gparted from the flash drive displays the 350 GB partition as almost full. Is there any way of fixing this, like forcing the system to rescan the partition and see there's more space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue using `ncdu`:

`sudo apt install ncdu`

`cd /`

`sudo ncdu`

That way I found out that all the log files I deleted from the flash drive had been moved to /.Trash-0/files/